# Objective variable is not defined in copris

Tags: scala

I'm using the [Akari solver in copris v.1.1](http://bach.istc.kobe-u.ac.jp/copris/puzzles/akari/)

Here is the code in scalademoapp.scala:

```
import java.lang.String 
import java.util.Arrays 

object scalademoapp extends App { 
    System.out.println(" test 1............."); 
    val a = new Array [String] (3); a(0)="-smt";
    a(1)="-v"; a(2)="c:\\akari.txt"; 
    System.out.println("test.............");
    System.out.println(a.deep.mkString("\n")); 
    Solver.main(a); 
    System.out.println("test4............."); 
}
```

This exception is raised when trying to execute the solver:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Objective
>   variable is not defined   at
>   jp.kobe_u.copris.sugar.Solver.findOptBody(Sugar.scala:631)    at
>   jp.kobe_u.copris.AbstractSolver$$anonfun$findOpt$1.apply$mcZ$sp(Solver.scala:266)
>     at
>   jp.kobe_u.copris.AbstractSolver$$anonfun$findOpt$1.apply(Solver.scala:264)
>     at
>   jp.kobe_u.copris.AbstractSolver$$anonfun$findOpt$1.apply(Solver.scala:264)
>     at jp.kobe_u.copris.AbstractSolver.measureTime(Solver.scala:205)    at
>   jp.kobe_u.copris.AbstractSolver.findOpt(Solver.scala:264)     at
>   jp.kobe_u.copris.CoprisTrait$class.findOpt(Copris.scala:52)   at
>   jp.kobe_u.copris.dsl$.findOpt(Copris.scala:92)    at
>   AbstractPuzzleSolver$class.findOptSolution(PuzzleSolver.scala:54)     at
>   Solver$.findOptSolution(Akari-v1-1.scala:37)  at
>   AbstractPuzzleSolver$class.solve(PuzzleSolver.scala:70)   at
>   Solver$.BoardPuzzleSolver$$super$solve(Akari-v1-1.scala:37)   at
>   BoardPuzzleSolver$class.solve(PuzzleSolver.scala:237)     at
>   Solver$.solve(Akari-v1-1.scala:37)    at
>   AbstractPuzzleSolver$class.main(PuzzleSolver.scala:163)   at
>   Solver$.main(Akari-v1-1.scala:37)     at
>   scalademoapp$.delayedEndpoint$scalademoapp$1(scalademoapp.scala:21)
>     at scalademoapp$delayedInit$body.apply(scalademoapp.scala:7)    at
>   scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)    at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
>     at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)    at
>   scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)   at
>   scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
>     at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)   at
>   scalademoapp$.main(scalademoapp.scala:7)  at
>   scalademoapp.main(scalademoapp.scala)

What is causing this exception?

Comment: it would be easier to help if you post your `scalademoapp.scala: 7`

Comment: here is scalademoapp.scala



import java.lang.String
import java.util.Arrays

object scalademoapp extends App {
System.out.println(" test 1.............");

val a = new Array [String] (3);
a(0)="-smt";
a(1)="-v";
a(2)="c:\\akari.txt";


System.out.println("test.............");
System.out.println(a.deep.mkString("\n"));
 Solver.main(a);
System.out.println("test4.............");
}

Comment: @chiva please add your code into question

Comment: @chiva see `case "-smt" :: solver :: rest` at `PuzzleSolver.scala` -  `-v` should be the last argument: `Solver.main(Array("-smt", "c:\\akari.txt", "-v"))`

Comment: You're welcome, by the way if you don't mention @dk14 in comment - I won't receive notification

Answer (score 0):

see `case "-smt" :: solver :: rest` at `PuzzleSolver.scala` - `-v` should be the last argument: `Solver.main(Array("-smt", "c:\\akari.txt", "-v"))`